# R markdown add list of figures to table of content

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to add the "list of figures" to my "table of content" in R Markdown?

My toc is working, but it shows only the chapters of the document but not the generated list of figures.

The list of figures is generated automatically by using \listoffigures in the code. But only the chapters which are added with # Chaptername are shown in the toc.